# Create message layout like telegram message view

Tags: android, android-layout, telegram

I want to create message layout like below. Please guide me. I used this [lib](https://github.com/himanshu-soni/ChatMessageView)

[image]

for this purpose but Mine message and other message don't show it's defined places I opened this issue at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316854/cannot-work-with-recyclerview-item-layout).

Comment: Just use 9 patch images for background of messages.

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681075/could-anyone-help-me-with-creating-9-patch-image-from-a-png-image